# VPN gateway connection partly disables internet connection through wifi

Tags: raspbian, vpn, hotspot

I recently tried to extend the functionality of my RPi to serve as a gateway through the (LogMeIn) Hamachi client.

Yet the RPi has been used as a wifi hotspot (with static ip for both, wlan0 and eth0 interface) through an adjusted routing table, `isc-dhcp-server` and `hostapd` service.

I used the following commands to install the given hamachi client:

1. `sudo apt-get install lsb-core`
2. `sudo dpkg -i logmein-hamachi_2.1.0.139-1_armhf.deb` (previously downloaded from the hamachi page)

After adding the client to the according Gateway-Network (within the LogMeIn central) and defining him as the gateway computer, I can't access the internet through my wifi anymore.

Note: If I define him as a simple network member, all is working fine, except for the missing gateway functionality.

Here is the `ifconfig` output before and after gateway assignment:

[before]

> eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr b8:27:eb:d4:45:cb
>             inet addr:192.168.0.12  Bcast:192.168.0.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
>             UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
>             RX packets:50449 errors:0 dropped:500 overruns:0 frame:0
>             TX packets:37562 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
>             collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
>             RX bytes:50402536 (48.0 MiB)  TX bytes:11077575 (10.5 MiB)
>
> lo        Link encap:Local Loopback
>             inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
>             UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
>             RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
>             TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
>             collisions:0 txqueuelen:0
>             RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)
>
> mon.wlan0 Link encap:UNSPEC  HWaddr
>   C0-4A-00-11-A6-65-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00
>             UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
>             RX packets:1492 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
>             TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
>             collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
>             RX bytes:207946 (203.0 KiB)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)
>
> wlan0     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr c0:4a:00:11:a6:65
>             inet addr:192.168.42.1  Bcast:192.168.42.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
>             UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
>             RX packets:38568 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
>             TX packets:50936 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
>             collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
>             RX bytes:10930199 (10.4 MiB)  TX bytes:52102904 (49.6 MiB)

[after]

> eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr b8:27:eb:d4:45:cb
>             inet6 addr: fe80::ba27:ebff:fed4:45cb/64 Scope:Link
>             UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
>             RX packets:93010 errors:0 dropped:1660 overruns:0 frame:0
>             TX packets:63709 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
>             collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
>             RX bytes:88368876 (84.2 MiB)  TX bytes:16586853 (15.8 MiB)
>
> ham0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 7a:79:00:00:00:00
>             inet addr:25.111.169.0  Bcast:25.255.255.255  Mask:255.0.0.0
>             inet6 addr: fe80::7879:ff:fe00:0/64 Scope:Link
>             UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1404  Metric:1
>             RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
>             TX packets:8 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
>             collisions:0 txqueuelen:500
>             RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:648 (648.0 B)
>
> ham1      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:23:c3:6f:a9:00
>             inet6 addr: fe80::223:c3ff:fe6f:a900/64 Scope:Link
>             UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1404  Metric:1
>             RX packets:28 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
>             TX packets:17 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
>             collisions:0 txqueuelen:500
>             RX bytes:1680 (1.6 KiB)  TX bytes:1116 (1.0 KiB)
>
> ham-br0   Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:23:c3:6f:a9:00
>             inet addr:192.168.0.12  Bcast:192.168.0.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
>             inet6 addr: fe80::ba27:ebff:fed4:45cb/64 Scope:Link
>             inet6 addr: 2a02:810d:8800:4630:ba27:ebff:fed4:45cb/64 Scope:Global
>             UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1404  Metric:1
>             RX packets:132 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
>             TX packets:106 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
>             collisions:0 txqueuelen:0
>             RX bytes:17593 (17.1 KiB)  TX bytes:14531 (14.1 KiB)
>
> lo        Link encap:Local Loopback
>             inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
>             inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
>             UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
>             RX packets:12 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
>             TX packets:12 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
>             collisions:0 txqueuelen:0
>             RX bytes:2544 (2.4 KiB)  TX bytes:2544 (2.4 KiB)
>
> mon.wlan0 Link encap:UNSPEC  HWaddr
>   C0-4A-00-11-A6-65-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00
>             UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
>             RX packets:4787 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
>             TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
>             collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
>             RX bytes:672816 (657.0 KiB)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)
>
> wlan0     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr c0:4a:00:11:a6:65
>             inet addr:192.168.42.1  Bcast:192.168.42.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
>             inet6 addr: fe80::c24a:ff:fe11:a665/64 Scope:Link
>             UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
>             RX packets:62203 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
>             TX packets:81248 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
>             collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
>             RX bytes:15953838 (15.2 MiB)  TX bytes:78108272 (74.4 MiB)

Only thing I can see is that there's no assigned IPv4 for `eth0`.

How can I fix this, in order to get the gateway as well as my wifi hotspot up and running?

Comment: I have the same problem in ubuntu, after a vpn conection the interface ham0 shows in the ifconfig, I dont know how to remove that